# hiding save buttons in admin if all fields are read only

Tags: django, django-admin

I use the following `get_readonly_fields` method to not allow editing of objects in django's admin interface:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj == None or request.user.is_superuser:
        return self.readonly_fields

    # marks all fields as readonly otherwise
    fields = [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields]
    return fields
```

This works perfectly, but the `save` and `save and continue editing` still show up. They won't do anything since all fields are read-only.

Hence my question: Is there a way to hide these `save` buttons dependent on whether all fields are read-only or not? How could I implement this?

**EDIT1:**

I'm aware on how to override the `admin/submit_line.html` template, but what I would like to do instead, is to set the `show_save`, `show_save_as_new` to `False` if I only have read-only fields. How can I change these variable values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In django/contrib/admin there is a file called submit_line.html which renders the buttons. To override them, in your templates directory, create a folder called admin, and in admin/submit_line.html you would modify it the way you want (based on certain rules). Please note that modifying it this way would affect every admin object-view page.

Comment: sure, I know how to override the admin template, but I want to a) either override it conditionally, or somehow pass a variable to it that will either show the save buttons or not (conditional on the read-only fields)